# How do I assign images to gallery id in Wordpress with shortcodes in Page Templates

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

My friend has asked me to help them move images around on their wordpress site. They have an image slideshow that runs along the bottom of the page and the image gallery that shows, depends on the page template used.

One template has the following code:

```
<?php 
$tagu = get_post_meta($post->ID,'bototm_gallery');
 ?>

<div class="flt box_bottom">
<ul style="margin-left:10px !important; width:100% !important;" class="sub_photo sub_photo_gigs" class="sub_photo">
    <?php echo do_shortcode($tagu['0']); ?>

</ul>`
```

---

and another page template shows this code:

```
<?php $tagu = get_post_meta($post->ID,'bototm_gallery'); ?>


<div class="flt box_bottom">

<div class="sv_footer_photo">

<?php echo do_shortcode($tagu['0']); ?>

</div>`
```

How do I add images to a specific gallery? I can't find a gallery id in the media library and/or I don't know where to find the class such as sv_footer_photo or sub_photo.

Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Wow, I've found it and sure enough it was simple.

I had to click on 'Screen Options' at the top of the page, tick the box for custom fields and then I can see the gallery image ids assigned to that page.